# CASE condition with IN clause in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to pass the in clause after case statement but facing error.

Condition is

```
AND (CASE order_date>sysdate 
      then fee_rate_type in ('REGULAR','BONUS')
      ELSE FEE_RATE_TYPE in ('REGULAR') END)
```

When i am passing single value instead of multiple (pass 'BONUS' insted of 'REGULAR','BONUS') then its working fine.

table structure:

```
ID  fee_rate    order_date
--  --------    ----------
1   REGULAR     02/02/2016
2   BONUS       02/02/2016
3   BONUS       02/02/2016
4   BONUS       02/02/2016
5   PROMO       02/02/2016
6   PROMO       02/02/2016
```

Please assist.

Comment: Could you show some sample data and the results you're expecting?

Comment: sure...sample data is :ID  fee_rate order_date
1 REGULAR sysdate+1
2 BONUS sysdate+2
3 BONUS sysdate+3
4 BONUS sysdate+4
5 PROMO sysdate+5
6 PROMO sysdate+6
expected output id 1,2,3,4 will pick .

Comment: Please edit your question to include this additional info

Comment: ID  fee_rate order_date
1 REGULAR sysdate+1
2 BONUS sysdate+2
3 BONUS sysdate+3
4 BONUS sysdate+4
5 PROMO sysdate+5
6 PROMO sysdate+6

Comment: Put it in the QUESTION !!!!!

Comment: There's no formatting in comments, we can't see the table structure.

Answer (score 1):

The `case` statement is an expression that returns a single value.  If you want to use `case`, then you need to return a value and do a comparison:

```
(CASE order_date > sysdate and fee_rate_type in ('REGULAR', 'BONUS') then 1
      order_date <= sysdate and FEE_RATE_TYPE in ('REGULAR') then 1
 END) = 1
```

However, I would encourage you not to use `case` in a `where` clause.  You can express this as simple conditions.  Here is one way:

```
((order_date > sysdate and fee_rate_type in ('REGULAR', 'BONUS') ) OR
 (order_date <= sysdate and FEE_RATE_TYPE in ('REGULAR') )
)
```

Or, perhaps:

```
(fee_rate_type = 'REGULAR' or
 (order_date > sysdate and fee_rate_type = 'BONUS')
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below query:

```
AND (CASE order_date>sysdate 
      then fee_rate_type = ALL ('REGULAR','BONUS')
      ELSE FEE_RATE_TYPE in ('REGULAR') END)
```

Comment: if you use ALL('REGULAR','BONUS') then if 'REGULAR' only has order_date > sysdate then the query will not work